# Server Side PDF Export Function

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Is there any way to "command" an PDF dashboard generation at server side without accessing to the report page from a browser?
Practically i would like to periodically generate an unattended PDF from specific Dashboards based on some scheduling and send those results by mail.

Comment: Calling the GVI Method passing the printReportBatch ACTION (and all the relative parameters) is considered as a good practice or not?

Comment: Yes no foreseen issue with that.